# Arch Linux on Mac Book Pro 2017 Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)

Tags: arch-linux, system-installation, bluetooth, macintosh

I wanted to install Arch Linux on my Mac Book Pro 2017 following [this article](https://medium.com/@laurynas.karvelis_95228/install-arch-linux-on-macbook-pro-11-2-retina-install-guide-for-year-2017-2034ceed4cb2).

However, when I boot into Arch Linux I get automatically logged in as root which should be fine. But when I want to type anything there is nothing happens and after few seconds I get this message:

```
[    17.3762281] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reset failed (-110)
```

How can solve the issue?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Which boot loader do you use? Did you try to boot in rescue mode?

Comment: @ortomala I use the UEFI boot loader.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and just wanted to add the response to your reddit thread about the same problem here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/8891vi/arch_linux_on_mac_book_pro_2017/

> [The keyboard is] still USB, but the keyboard now also includes the touchbar (even if its not there), so it doesnt work with the standard keyboard drivers.

So, just attach a USB keyboard and you are able to type.